# Visual Studio 2010 c# process.start being ignored

Tags: c#, process.start

I put this line of code in my program:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox.exe", "http://sample.com//page.html");
```

and I also tried with the full path:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "http://sample.com//page.html");
```

I have the appropriate using statements.
My problem is the line is being completely ignored.
Since there are no errors or aborts then a try/catch won't help.
What am I missing?

**Note:**  does it make a difference that my program is running as a *windows service*?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you sure the process isn't started? Have you checked it in the task manager?

Comment: you're right ... it is started ... only it's hidden ... why is it hidden and how do I make it appear with the indicated page?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your system, rather than the code. End all processes in TM and reboot your machine maybe.

Comment: Firefox doesn't even show as an icon on the bottom as if it's not running ... yet task manager shows it is ... I have reboot many times and retried.

Comment: I tried both Snippets and it works well with FF 38. I think it is a setting, a bug or similiar...

Comment: so you see firefox open with a page then?

Comment: does it make a difference that my program is running as a windows service?

Comment: If you ran that command and argument from a command console, does the page open?

Comment: _"does it make a difference that my program is running as a **windows service?**"_ - yes.  Services by default may not interact with the desktop which generally means spawned GUI appears won't appear either

Comment: Thanks Micky.  Don't know how to give you credit for that since there is no answer.

Comment: @XiVix done. see below

Comment: Have a look at the description of the [Session 0 Isolation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx) which is the culprit here. That's why many programs failed in post-XP Windows'. The recommended workaround is to have 2 programs, the service and a helper program hidden in the user desktop, both use IPC to communicate and the desktop program is the one to issue the `Proccess.Start` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indicated you are running as a Windows Service.  WS by default may not interact with the desktop which generally means spawned GUI processes won't appear either.

You have two choices

1. Change your app so that it is **not** a Windows Service
2. Change the settings in **Computer Management.Services**. right-click, **Properties**; **Log-on** tab and tick **Allow service to interact with desktop**.

Interact with desktop is not entirely recommended as it sorts of defeats the purpose of services.  Plus it may require that you are logged in in order to work

Comment: I don't seem to find a Computer Management.Services

Comment: Right-click **My Computer**; click **Manage**; select **Services and Applications**; click **Services**.  Alternatively, **Start > Run** "services.msc" is a nice quick way to get there.

Comment: oh ... I meant from visual studio ... I wouldn't expect the end user to do that ... it would have to be programmed in to the service itself